# Import variable assignments from external files into different contexts

Tags: import, files-and-directories, contexts

(I use *Mathematica* 9.0.1 on OS X 10.10.5.)

I have two text files. One is named `file1.txt` with the contents

```
a = 4
b = 15
c = 23
```

and the other is `file2.txt` with the contents

```
a = 8
b = 16
c = 42
```

The end result I would like to achieve is a Mathematica notebook with the following variable definitions in place:

```
file1`a = 4
file2`a = 8
file1`b = 15
file2`b = 16
file1`c = 23
file2`c = 42
```

The approach that came to my mind was

```
Begin["file1`"]
Get["file1.txt"]
End[]

Begin["file2`"]
Get["file2.txt"]
End[]
```

But the `Get`s didn't seem to respect the context-switching, instead just loading everything into the Notebook's context. Is there a way of repairing this approach?

Or is there a better way to accomplish the end goal here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ReadList` seems to work as you intended when used instead of `Get` in your code:

```
ClearAll["file1`*", "file2`*"]

Begin["file1`"]
ReadList["file1.txt", "Expression"]
End[]

Begin["file2`"]
ReadList["file2.txt", "Expression"]
End[]
```

On my system, I obtain:

```
?file1`*
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively you can of course check the values themselves:

```
a          (* Out: a *)
file1`a    (* Out: 4 *)
file2`a    (* Out: 8 *)
```

Comment: One and done! Thanks.